# Searching between two numbers(percentage)

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have this code;

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "Toom13371!";
$lowfreq = $_POST['Lowfreq']; # User-Supplied Data.             I'm A
$highfreq = $_POST['Highfreq']; # User-Supplied Data.        Placeholder yo.
$construction = $_POST['construction_type']; # User-Supplied Data.   Still holding
$connector = $_POST['connector_type']; # User-Supplied Data.                that place.
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=filters", $username, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


//print
//echo $highfreq;
//echo $lowfreq;
//echo $connector;
//echo $construction; #tests

$condition = array(); #sets condition as array
$strcond = ""; #sets $strcond as "empty"
if (!empty($lowfreq)) {
    $condition[] = " start_passband = $lowfreq";
}

if (!empty($highfreq)) {
    $condition[] = " stop_passband = $highfreq";
}

if (!empty($construction)) {
    $condition[] = " construction_type = '$construction'";
}

if (!empty($connector)) {
    $condition[] = " connector_type = '$connector'";
}
if (!empty($condition)) {
$tempx = implode(' AND', $condition);
$tempy = " WHERE " . $tempx;
print $tempx;
unset($condition); #clears the array $condition
$condition= array(); 
$strcond = $tempy;
//print $strcond;
    //$condition .= " ".implode(' AND', $condition);
    }

    // Select some data
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, type_code, connector_type, construction_type, start_passband,     stop_passband, lower_stopband_start, lower_stopband_stop, upper_stopband_start, upper_stopband_stop      FROM filter_bandpass $strcond");

// Execute the query, replacing the placeholders with their true value
$sth->execute(array());
```

What I want to do is use $lowfreq/$highreq and then search between +/- 20% of that to return all values where its $lowfreq +/- 20% and then $highfreq +/- 20%.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how to get percentages:

```
$lowfreqlow = $lowfreq * 0.8;
$lowfreqhigh = $lowfreq * 1.2;

$highfreqlow = $highfreq * 0.8;
$highfreqhigh = $highfreq * 1.2;
```

Then something like `"... WHERE lowfreqcolumn BETWEEN ".$lowfreqlow." AND ".$lowfreqhigh." AND highfreqcolumn BETWEEN ".$lowfreqlow." AND ".$lowfreqhigh` for the new SQL query.

Comment: So say they search for $lowfreq= 3 and $highfreq = 5, it will return all data where $lowfreq = 2.4 and 3.6 and $highfreq = 4 and 6

Comment: The only issue is im using a string, $strcond for the SQL query, was seeing if i could do it without having to change that.

Comment: In that case, just set `$strcond = 'WHERE lowfreqcolumn BETWEEN ".$lowfreqlow." AND ".$lowfreqhigh." AND highfreqcolumn BETWEEN ".$lowfreqlow." AND ".$lowfreqhigh';`